# How do you keep number formatting when copying a table from Excel to Word? (Office 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I want to copy a table from Excel to Word and keep the number formatting (*not* table formatting as in cell or font size). Is there any way I can do so? For example, if it says "1.6E-01" in Excel, it changes to "0.16" when copied to Word. I don't want that, I want to keep the "E-". Or, if the number in Excel has 3 decimal places, suddenly it displays more when copied to Word. I want to keep it 3 places.

It's a large table so retyping or copying the text one-by-one will take hours. Paste as Picture is not an option either (assignment rules).

Also, this might be relevant: in the Excel file, I use conditional formatting to change how the numbers are displayed according to their value. For example, numbers between 0.1 and 0.01 are automatically formatted to have 3 decimal places, and numbers smaller than 0.01 are automatically displayed in the Scientific format.

Thanks :D

Comment: Word has no conditional formatting like Excel, you will need to get into VBA (not an easy project).

Comment: Hi harrymc, I'll be honest with you, this is the first time I've heard about VBA lol. Learning it solely for this task seems quite an overkill. I might read more about it in the future though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

Paste --> Paste Special --> Formatted Text (RTF)